# Bootstrap-Dropdown not functioning [RAILS]

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I working on using the Bootstrap-Dropdown menu for rails, but currently it isn't functioning. When I click on the dropdown link, it adds a '#' to the url and nothing else changes.

"_header.html.erb"

```
<% if signed_in? %>
        <li><%= link_to "Device", '/devices' %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Users", users_path %></li>
        <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Account <b class="caret"></b>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Settings", edit_user_path(current_user) %></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li>
              <%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, method: "delete" %>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      <% else %>
        <li><%= link_to "Sign in", signin_path %></li>
      <% end %>
```

application.js

```
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap-dropdown
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

application.html.erb

```
  <head>
<title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
<%= javascript_include_tag "https://js.stripe.com/v1/" %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all",
                                       "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
<%= render 'layouts/shim' %>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was to remove `bootstrap` from the list and just keep `bootstrap-dropdown`

```
//= require bootstrap-dropdown
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Works now

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap requires jQuery, so likely you'll need jQuery to be ahead of Bootstrap in the load order.  You also don't need to include bootstrap-dropdown separately:

change

```
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap-dropdown
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

to

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
```